# Random card game

Tags: python, random

I'm currently doing a random card game project, the program should show 5random cards to the user, (first question): I dont get how to random a list of letters and heres my code:

```
def play():
    hand = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K"]

    for i in range(len(hand)):
        card = random.choice[{hand},4]   

    print "User >>>> ",card
    return card
```

Second question: If the user wants to change the position of the card . the user should type in the no. of position change, then the program should change the card randomly. for example : AJ891, user typed: 1 , --> A2891. what should I do? Here's my original code but it doesn't work out

```
def ask_pos():
    pos_change = raw_input("From which position (and on) would you want to change? (0 to 4)? ")
    while not (pos_change.isdigit()):
        print "Your input must be an integer number"
        pos_change = raw_input("From which position (and on) would you want to change? (0 to 4)? ")
        if (pos_change > 4) :
            print "Sorry the value has to be between 0 and 4, please re-type"
            pos_change = raw_input("From which position (and on) would you want to change? (0 to 4)? ")
    return pos_change

    hand = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K"]

    for i in range(len(hand)):
        card = random.choice[{hand},4]
        new = random.choice[{hand},1]

            for i in range(len(card)):
                if (card[i] == pos_change):
                    card = card + new

    return card
```

Comment: `random.choice[{hand},4]` Did you made this up or someone told you to use this syntax on April Fools? There are so many things wrong with this line I don't even know where to start

Comment: This code won't run; so please paste the running code.

Comment: random.sample(hand,5), returns a list with 5 items of hand randomly. (import random, or from random import sample, but then -> sample(hand,5)

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
random.choice[{hand},4]
```

That won't work, bad syntax error. Also choice won't do the trick, sample is what you want:

```
random.sample(hand, 5)
```

2)

```
pick = random.sample(hand, 5)

change = 2  # Entered by the user

pick[change] = random.choice([x for x in hand if x not in pick])
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

```
import random
hands = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K"]
def play():
    cards = random.sample(hands,5)
    print "User >>>> ", cards
    return cards
```

`random.choice[{hand},4]` should result in a syntax error. Firstly, calling functions you use parenthesis `()` and not brackets `[]`. Also, I don't see why you need to put braces `{}` around hand, as it's already a list so nothing needs to be done.

I re-wrote your second question:

```
def ask_pos(hand):
    while 1:
        pos_change = raw_input("From which position (and on) would you want to change? (0 to 4)? ")
        if int(pos_change) < 0 or int(pos_change) > 4:
            continue
        else:
            break
    hand[int(pos_change)] = random.choice(hands)
    return hand
```

When run:

```
>>> myhand = play()
User >>>>  ['6', '8', 'A', '9', '4']

>>> ask_pos(myhand)
From which position (and on) would you want to change? (0 to 4)? 0
['Q', '8', 'A', '9', '4']
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for the help. I tried your code in my program but there's an error, it says :

   NameError: global name 'hand' is not defined

Comment: What abouts are you trying to do? i.e, where does the error come from

Comment: I'm stuck on the second part of the code, the program couldn't change the position of the card.

Comment: Are you putting in a parameter? to call the function, do `ask_pos(yourlist)`. Make sure the `yourlist` is a list, like I've shown in the example

Comment: yes I did, but when I run the program, there's an error saying that TypeError: ask_pos() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: That's impossible. If you have nothing in-between the parenthesis, then you're not putting in an argument (parameter, argument, same thing btw)

Answer (score 0):

You could use random.randrange(number), and then pull out the index at that position.